# Unexpected interaction with String and File

Tags: java, string, file, directory

I have following pieces of code:

```
    if (e.getSource() == theView.addButton) {

            System.out.println("Add Button clicked");
            theView.setBotTextArea("Adding category...");

            File directory = new File(theModel.getDirectory() + theView.getCategoryNameInput());

            boolean isDirectoryCreated = directory.mkdir();

            if(isDirectoryCreated) { 

                System.out.println("Created new directory in: " + directory);

            } else if (directory.exists()) { 

                System.out.println("Category already exists!");

            }               

        }
```

This is part of the `ActionListener`'s `ActionPerformed()` method.

```
private File directory = new File("C:/Users/Lotix/Desktop/TestFolder/");
public File getDirectory() { 

    return directory;

}
```

What i expect this method to do is to create a subfolder in the chosen directory. However, for some reason unknown to me, it creates completly another folder on my desktop instead of **TestFolder**.

I tried `theModel.getDirectory().toString()` and manipulating the variable but to no avail. The solution i came up with is to simply add forward slash between
`theModel.getDirectory()` and `theView.getCategoryNameInput()` such as this:

`File directory = new File(theModel.getDirectory() + "/" + theView.getCategoryNameInput());`

However, when i concatenate `File` variable with another `String` it works perfectly fine.

What gives?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: I read through it, but i'm afraid i still don't understand. Do you mind elaborating?

Comment: I mean that instead of concatenating strings to create a File from a directory and a file name, you should use the appropriate File constructor: the one I linked to, which takes a directory as first argument, and a file name as the second argument.

Comment: I see. That's very convienient. Thank you for helping me out. Off to rebuilding my methods.

Answer (score 0):

*Any* file you create in your own Desktop directory appears on your desktop. That's what the folder is *for.*

This doesnt have anything to do with 'interaction with String and File', or Java.